# Number of unwrapped items per row for a certain width and height of container

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a code sample at [demo code](https://js.do/sun21170/66209) that displays li elements within a ul in a flow-like manner i.e. with `display:inline`.

I need to determine the number of `complete` li items displayed without wrapping for each row in the ul element. I have written code for this in document ready event using jquery, but it is not giving correct results since its including wrapped li items.

**Question**:

How can I exclude the li items which are wrapping from being included in items per row count? I need to exclude the li item that is wrapping as not within this row or next row, since its not completely displayed in a row.

The same code sample is as given below:

```
<h2>Items per row</h2>
 <div id="mathDiv"> 
  <ul>
     <li>Polynomial</li>
     <li>Binomial Theorem</li>
     <li>Quadratic Equation</li>
     <li>Simple Equation</li>
     <li>Permutations Combinations</li>
     <li>Matrices</li>
     <li>Determinants</li>
     <li>Vectors</li>
     <li>Arithmetic Series</li> 
     <li>Geometric Series</li>
     <li>Binomial nth Term<li>
  </ul>
 </div>

 <div id="msgDiv"></div>

 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  //var firstLiTop =  $("li:nth-child(1)").position().top;
  //var fourthLiTop =  $("li:nth-child(4)").position().top;
  //alert("firstLiTop = " + firstLiTop + " , fourthLiTop = " + fourthLiTop);

  var currentTop;
  var itemsInRowCount = 0;
  var currentRow = 0;
  var itemCount = [];

  $("#mathDiv ul li").each(function(index) {
    var liTop = $(this).position().top;
    if(!currentTop) {
       currentTop = liTop;
       currentRow = 0;
   }  

   //alert("currentTop = " + currentTop + " , liTop = " + liTop);

   //row changing logic
   if(currentTop === liTop) {
     itemsInRowCount++;
   } else {//we are in a new row
     currentRow++;
     itemCount.push(itemsInRowCount);//item count for last row
     itemsInRowCount = 1;
   }
   if(index > 0) {
     currentTop = liTop;
   }
  });
  $("#msgDiv").html("Item count for each row are : " + itemCount.join());
 });
 </script>
<style>
div ul {
  display:block;
  border:1px red solid;
  height:170px;
  margin:0;
  padding-left:2px;

}

div ul li {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;
  margin-right:5px;
  border-bottom:2px solid green;


}

#mathDiv {
  width:340px;
  height:200px;
  border: 1px solid purple;
  display:block;
  padding-left:5px;
  padding-right:5px;
  padding-top:0;
}

#msgDiv {
 color:red;
  margin-top:5px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to exclude the wrapped items from being counted in items per row count. The changed sample which now works is at [Working demo sample with changes for wrapped items](https://js.do/sun21170/resolved-determine-number-of-items-per-row-in-display-inline)

I changed the code snippet which decides if its a new row to as below.

The logic I use in code below for knowing if an item is wrapping is to determine the left of first item in the new row and compare it with the left of first item in entire li collection; if they are equal then the last item in previous row did not wrap else it wrapped.

```
   //row changing logic
   if(currentTop === liTop) {
     itemsInRowCount++;
   } else {//we are in a new row
     //if the first item in new row is not left aligned with the first li
     //then we have an item flowing/wrapping into this new row
      if($(this).position().left !== $("li:nth-child(1)").position().left) {
       itemsInRowCount--;
      }

     currentRow++;
     itemCount.push(itemsInRowCount);//item count for last row
     itemsInRowCount = 1;
   }
```